# Python code running in steps rather than as a whole

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a bit of code that will read a transcript and search for a list of phrases which are stored in a different text file. If a match is found, it prints the matching line followed by the next line (response), this is stored in a result text file. This result text file is then read again, and put into an excel file in its designated area.

I have the code working to the point where it generates the results and puts them in the excel spreadsheet where it needs to go, however. **The data in the results are not updating.** I have the code randomly choosing a transcript out of a list of 10 to scatter the results, however **I have to run the entire code over and over again to get all 5 category results updated**. The five categories are:

**B /
A / 
N / 
T / 
P**

Does anyone know where I am going wrong here? Or even how to get all of the analysis sections to run at the same time rather than one by one?

My code is as follows:

```
import sys
import os, random
random_file=random.choice(os.listdir("/Transcripts/"))

file = ("Transcripts/" + (random_file))


#Budget Analysis
sep = '-' * 30 + '\n'
with open(file) as t_file,\
    open ('b_result.txt') as b_result_file,\
    open('BANTP Questions/B.txt') as b_file, \
    open('BANTP Follow Up Questions/B.txt') as b_up_file:
    t_lines = t_file.readlines()
    b_lines = [l.strip() for l in b_file.readlines()]
    f_lines = b_up_file.readlines()
    # Checking each transcription line
    for counter, t_line in enumerate(t_lines):
        # Checking if any P-line is in the T-line
        b_in_t = any([b_line in t_line for b_line in b_lines])
        if b_in_t:
            # Printing Q and A
            answer = t_lines[counter+1]
            print(f'{t_line}{sep}{answer}{sep}', end='', file=open("b_result.txt", "w"))
            # Checking if positive
            if 'yes' in answer.lower() or 'yeah' in answer.lower():
                # Grabbing the next 100 lines to check them for follow-ups
                batch = t_lines[counter+2:min(counter+100, len(t_lines))]
                for index, line in enumerate(batch):
                    # Checking the line if it contains a question
                    f_in_t = any([f_line in line for f_line in f_lines])
                    if f_in_t:
                        # Printing Q and A
                        answer = batch[index+1]
                        print(f'{line}{sep}{answer}{sep}', end='', file=open("b_result.txt", "a"))
                    elif counter % 2 == 0:
                        # No follow-up - move to the next question
                        # Except it's customer's reply
                        break

#Authority Analysis
sep = '-' * 30 + '\n'
with open(file) as t_file,\
    open ('BANTP Results/a_result.txt') as a_result_file,\
    open('BANTP Questions/A.txt') as a_file, \
    open('BANTP Follow Up Questions/A.txt') as a_up_file:
    t_lines = t_file.readlines()
    b_lines = [l.strip() for l in a_file.readlines()]
    f_lines = a_up_file.readlines()
    # Checking each transcription line
    for counter, t_line in enumerate(t_lines):
        # Checking if any P-line is in the T-line
        b_in_t = any([b_line in t_line for b_line in b_lines])
        if b_in_t:
            # Printing Q and A
            answer = t_lines[counter+1]
            print(f'{t_line}{sep}{answer}{sep}', end='', file=open("BANTP Results/a_result.txt", "w"))
            # Checking if positive
            if 'yes' in answer.lower() or 'yeah' in answer.lower():
                # Grabbing the next 100 lines to check them for follow-ups
                batch = t_lines[counter+2:min(counter+100, len(t_lines))]
                for index, line in enumerate(batch):
                    # Checking the line if it contains a question
                    f_in_t = any([f_line in line for f_line in f_lines])
                    if f_in_t:
                        # Printing Q and A
                        answer = batch[index+1]
                        print(f'{line}{sep}{answer}{sep}', end='', file=open("BANTP Results/a_result.txt", "a"))
                    elif counter % 2 == 0:
                        # No follow-up - move to the next question
                        # Except it's customer's reply
                        break



#Need Analysis
sep = '-' * 30 + '\n'
with open(file) as t_file,\
    open ('BANTP Results/n_result.txt') as n_result_file,\
    open('BANTP Questions/N.txt') as n_file, \
    open('BANTP Follow Up Questions/N.txt') as n_up_file:
    t_lines = t_file.readlines()
    b_lines = [l.strip() for l in n_file.readlines()]
    f_lines = n_up_file.readlines()
    # Checking each transcription line
    for counter, t_line in enumerate(t_lines):
        # Checking if any P-line is in the T-line
        b_in_t = any([b_line in t_line for b_line in b_lines])
        if b_in_t:
            # Printing Q and A
            answer = t_lines[counter+1]
            print(f'{t_line}{sep}{answer}{sep}', end='', file=open("BANTP Results/n_result.txt", "w"))
            # Checking if positive
            if 'yes' in answer.lower() or 'yeah' in answer.lower():
                # Grabbing the next 100 lines to check them for follow-ups
                batch = t_lines[counter+2:min(counter+100, len(t_lines))]
                for index, line in enumerate(batch):
                    # Checking the line if it contains a question
                    f_in_t = any([f_line in line for f_line in f_lines])
                    if f_in_t:
                        # Printing Q and A
                        answer = batch[index+1]
                        print(f'{line}{sep}{answer}{sep}', end='', file=open("BANTP Results/n_result.txt", "a"))
                    elif counter % 2 == 0:
                        # No follow-up - move to the next question
                        # Except it's customer's reply
                        break


#Timeline Analysis
sep = '-' * 30 + '\n'
with open(file) as t_file,\
    open ('BANTP Results/t_result.txt') as time_result_file,\
    open('BANTP Questions/T.txt') as time_file, \
    open('BANTP Follow Up Questions/T.txt') as time_up_file:
    t_lines = t_file.readlines()
    b_lines = [l.strip() for l in time_file.readlines()]
    f_lines = time_up_file.readlines()
    # Checking each transcription line
    for counter, t_line in enumerate(t_lines):
        # Checking if any P-line is in the T-line
        b_in_t = any([b_line in t_line for b_line in b_lines])
        if b_in_t:
            # Printing Q and A
            answer = t_lines[counter+1]
            print(f'{t_line}{sep}{answer}{sep}', end='', file=open("BANTP Results/t_result.txt", "w"))
            # Checking if positive
            if 'yes' in answer.lower() or 'yeah' in answer.lower():
                # Grabbing the next 100 lines to check them for follow-ups
                batch = t_lines[counter+2:min(counter+100, len(t_lines))]
                for index, line in enumerate(batch):
                    # Checking the line if it contains a question
                    f_in_t = any([f_line in line for f_line in f_lines])
                    if f_in_t:
                        # Printing Q and A
                        answer = batch[index+1]
                        print(f'{line}{sep}{answer}{sep}', end='', file=open("BANTP Results/t_result.txt", "a"))
                    elif counter % 2 == 0:
                        # No follow-up - move to the next question
                        # Except it's customer's reply
                        break



#Partner Analysis
sep = '-' * 30 + '\n'
with open(file) as t_file,\
    open ('BANTP Results/p_result.txt') as p_result_file,\
    open('BANTP Questions/P.txt') as p_file, \
    open('BANTP Follow Up Questions/P.txt') as p_up_file:
    t_lines = t_file.readlines()
    p_lines = [l.strip() for l in p_file.readlines()]
    f_lines = p_up_file.readlines()
    # Checking each transcription line
    for counter, t_line in enumerate(t_lines):
        # Checking if any P-line is in the T-line
        p_in_t = any([p_line in t_line for p_line in p_lines])
        if p_in_t:
            # Printing Q and A
            answer = t_lines[counter+1]
            print(f'{t_line}{sep}{answer}{sep}', end='', file=open("BANTP Results/p_result.txt", "w"))
            # Checking if positive
            if 'yes' in answer.lower() or 'yeah' in answer.lower():
                # Grabbing the next 100 lines to check them for follow-ups
                batch = t_lines[counter+2:min(counter+100, len(t_lines))]
                for index, line in enumerate(batch):
                    # Checking the line if it contains a question
                    f_in_t = any([f_line in line for f_line in f_lines])
                    if f_in_t:
                        # Printing Q and A
                        answer = batch[index+1]
                        print(f'{line}{sep}{answer}{sep}', end='', file=open("BANTP Results/p_result.txt", "a"))
                    elif counter % 2 == 0:
                        # No follow-up - move to the next question
                        # Except it's customer's reply
                        break




import csv

with open('Testing2File.csv') as file: 
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(file, lineterminator='\n', fieldnames=["Call Number", "P Audio Name", "P Response", "P Category"])
    for row in csvReader:
        CallNumber = (row['Call Number'])

if CallNumber == "Number":
    number = 1
else:
    number = int(CallNumber)
    number += 1

B_result=open('BANTP Results/b_result.txt')
B_lines=B_result.readlines()

A_result=open('BANTP Results/a_result.txt')
A_lines=A_result.readlines()

N_result=open('BANTP Results/n_result.txt')
N_lines=N_result.readlines()

T_result=open('BANTP Results/t_result.txt')
T_lines=T_result.readlines()

P_result=open('BANTP Results/p_result.txt')
P_lines=P_result.readlines()

B_Response = B_lines[2]
A_Response = A_lines[2]
N_Response = N_lines[2]
T_Response = T_lines[2]
P_Response = P_lines[2]

B_Question = B_lines[0]
A_Question = A_lines[0]
N_Question = N_lines[0]
T_Question = T_lines[0]
P_Question = P_lines[0]

#Budget if
if "yes" in B_Response.lower() or "yeah" in B_Response.lower() or "yep" in B_Response.lower() or "right" in B_Response.lower():
    B_Category = "Certain Yes"
elif "i think so" in B_Response.lower():
    B_Category = "Uncertain Yes"
elif "i'm not sure" in B_Response.lower():
    B_Category = "Uncertain No"
elif "no" in B_Response.lower():
    B_Category = "Certain No"
else:
    B_Category = "Other"

#Authority if
if "recommender" in A_Response.lower() or "recommends" in A_Response.lower() or "recommend" in A_Response.lower()  or "recommended" in A_Response.lower():
    A_Category = "Recommender"
elif "final decision maker" in A_Response.lower() or "final decision" in A_Response.lower():
    A_Category = "Final Decision Maker"
else:
    A_Category = "Other"

#Need if
if "yes" in N_Response.lower() or "yeah" in N_Response.lower() or "yep" in N_Response.lower() or "right" in N_Response.lower():
    N_Category = "Certain Yes"
elif "i think so" in N_Response.lower():
    N_Category = "Uncertain Yes"
elif "i'm not sure" in N_Response.lower():
    N_Category = "Uncertain No"
elif "no" in N_Response.lower():
    N_Category = "Certain No"
else:
    N_Category = "Other"

#Time if
if "couple of months" in T_Response.lower() or "six months" in T_Response.lower():
    T_Category = "6 Months"
elif "one year" in T_Response.lower():
    T_Category = "12 Months"
elif "two years" in T_Response.lower():
    T_Category = "24 Months"
elif "three years" in T_Response.lower():
    T_Category = "36 Months"
else:
    T_Category = "Other"

#Partner if
if "yes" in P_Response.lower() or "yeah" in P_Response.lower() or "yep" in P_Response.lower() or "right" in P_Response.lower() or "i spoke with" in P_Response.lower() or "i spoke to" in P_Response.lower():
    P_Category = "Certain Yes"
elif "i think so" in P_Response.lower():
    P_Category = "Uncertain Yes"
elif "i'm not sure" in P_Response.lower():
    P_Category = "Uncertain No"
elif "no" in P_Response.lower():
    P_Category = "Certain No"
else:
    P_Category = "Other"

with open('Testing2File.csv', 'a') as file:
    csvWriter = csv.writer(file, lineterminator='\n')

    csvWriter.writerow([number, random_file, "", B_Question, B_Response, B_Category, "", A_Question, A_Response, A_Category, "", N_Question, N_Response, N_Category, "", T_Question, T_Response, T_Category, "", P_Question, P_Response, P_Category])


# with open('Testing2File.csv', 'w') as file:
#   csvWriter = csv.writer(file, lineterminator='\n')

#   csvWriter.writerow(["", "", "", "Budget", "", "", "", "Authority", "", "", "", "Need", "", "", "", "Time", "", "", "", "Partner"])
#   csvWriter.writerow(["Number", "Audio File", "", "Question", "Response", "Category", "", "Question", "Response", "Category", "", "Question", "Response", "Category", "", "Question", "Response", "Category", "", "Question", "Response", "Category"])
```

Comment: Most of your code can be moved in functions to make it more readable. There are many repeating fragments/logics.

Comment: Not that easy to understand your problem. It would be really helpful if you could strip your code down to the issue and also post the desired result. Something like: this is the input, this is the expected output and this is what I have done until now.

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem but I see you have the same code with different filenames so you should put code once in function and run this function many time but with different values (different filenames). For `if/else` at the end you could put values on list like `["yes", "yeah"]` and use `for`-loop to work with it. And you could use `.lower()` only once - like `B_Response = B_lines[2].lower()`

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code may probably be that you open result file twice: in `with` block and in `print` function:

```
with open(file) as t_file,\
open ('b_result.txt') as b_result_file,\
```

and

```
print(f'{line}{sep}{answer}{sep}', end='', file=open("b_result.txt", "a"))
```

try to not open the file in `with` block or pass `b_result_file` into the print function instead of reopening it again, but use a modifier `a` in it